# A limit of a fraction with sin in both the numerator and denominator

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to find $$\underset{x\rightarrow\pi}{\lim}\frac{\sin\left(ax\right)}{\sin(bx)}$$

I'm thinking of transforming this fraction into something that I can then 'process' with $$\underset{y\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{\sin y}{y}=1$$

I just don't know how to do it. My idea was to introduce a new variable $t = \pi-x$, but that doesn't seem to bear any fruit: $$\underset{t\rightarrow0}{\lim}\frac{\sin\left(a\left(\pi-t\right)\right)}{\sin\left(b\left(\pi-t\right)\right)}$$ because the expression in the sin brackets in both cases still does not approach $0$.

How can I compute that limit?
I appreciate any help.

Comment: This is only an issue if both $a,b$ are integers. In that case, expand the sin brackets using $\sin (A-B) = \sin A\cos B - \cos A\sin B$.

Comment: If $b$ is not an integrer, then $\sin b x \to \sin b\pi \neq 0$ and the limit follows directly from continuity. Are you missing any assumption?

Comment: The limit does not have to exist.

Comment: @DIdier_ No, the problem was given with no assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are not integers with $\sin(b\pi)\neq 0$ then the limit is given by

$$\frac{\sin\left(a\pi\right)}{\sin(b\pi)}$$

for $a$ and $b$ integers we obtain an indeterminate form $\frac 0 0$ and we can proceed by l'Hospital's rule.

---

To proceed without l'Hospital's rule we can use that

- $\sin ((2k)(\pi+x))=\sin (2kx)$
- $\sin ((2k+1)(\pi+x))=-\sin ((2k+1)x)$

therefore by $t=\pi -x \to 0$ we reduce to

$$\frac{\sin\left(ax\right)}{\sin(bx)}=\frac{\sin\left(a(\pi +t)\right)}{\sin(b(\pi +t))}=\pm \frac{\sin\left(at\right)}{\sin(bt)}$$

with the sign depending upon the parity of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: And if they are integers?

Comment: @alekscooper I have already considered this case. If they are integers we can use l'Hospital or as an alternative the method I have indicated. Let try with some numerical example, that is $(\sin (4x))/(\sin(3x))$ or $(\sin (5x))/(\sin(3x))$ or $(\sin (4x))/(\sin(2x))$ to see how it works.